# Prove $\sum\limits_{z=r}^{\infty}\begin{pmatrix}z\\r\end{pmatrix}p^r(1-p)^r=\dfrac{1}{p}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to prove
$$\sum\limits_{z=r}^{\infty}\begin{pmatrix}z\\r\end{pmatrix}p^r(1-p)^{z-r}=\dfrac{1}{p},$$
with $0<p<1$?

I'm not have idea. I just know the binomial theorem, it look similar with series above.
$$\sum\limits_{x=0}^{n}\begin{pmatrix}n\\x\end{pmatrix}a^{n-x}b^x=(a+b)^n,$$
So how to proof it?

Comment: This can't be correct as written.  The left side is a constant (i.e. not depending on $p$) times $p^r(1-p)^r$, the right is not.

Comment: Indeed, as written the left hand side is just $\infty.$

Comment: I'm typo. $p^r(1-p)^r$ should be $p^r(1-p)^{z-r}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can start with a similar identity:

$$ \sum_{z=r}^{\infty} \binom{z-1}{r-1} p^r (1-p)^{z-r} = 1$$

One way to prove this identity is to consider an experiment where we repeatedly flip a coin which has probability $p$ on landing on heads, and record the number of flips which were required to get to $r$ heads. The terms of the series each represent the probability that $z$ flips were required to get $r$ heads, and clearly the sum over $z\geq r$ is equal to $1.$

Applying this result, along with the identity $\binom{z}{r} = \binom{z-1}{r-1} + \binom{z-1}{r}$ shows that your sum is equal to

$$ 1 + \frac{1-p}{p} = \frac{1}{p}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+r}{r} p^n = \frac{1}{(1-p)^{r+1}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
You probably need to look carefully at how you got to the formula stated in the question.